# *Simple* FLV player (no logo, no advertisement)

Tags: drupal

I'm looking for a simple FLV player for my flv videos on Drupal.
I just want Play / Pause Button, mute volume option and eventually progress bar... (without logo or commercials)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) is GPL

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [swftools](http://drupal.org/project/swftools).

Answer (score 1):

There's always [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/).

It is used on a lot of sites and it's free of charge. It's simple to use and set up.

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer looks good